# Differences between how the find command interprets units of size

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, find

When I issue

```
find / \( -type f -size +10M \) -and \( -type f -size -1G \)
```

I don't get any results. However, when I type

```
find / \( -type f -size +10M \) -and \( -type f -size -1000M \)
```

the command returns a number of file names.

What's wrong?  Can't I use different unit of measurement in both sides of the `-and` operator?

Comment: duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275925/4667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### find and size

The default unit of size for the `find` command is a block of 512 bytes.

Confusingly, when you specify a file size in units such as kB, MB or GB, `find` **rounds up** the file size and uses that figure before testing against the `size` predicate.

E.g., when the size predicate is expressed in GB (`-size -1G`), the size of a 900MB file is rounded up to 1GB – which isn’t less than 1GB so such a file won’t be returned by `-size -1G`.  To find files that are smaller than 1GB, the size should be specified in smaller units:

```
find -size -1024M
```

See this [answer by Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50765/22812) to a related question on Unix and Linux.

> `find . -size -1M` will only show file of size less than 1M, that is 0M.
>   Yes, I know, it's confusing.

#### Official documentation

In the *POSIX* manual page for `find`, the `size` predicate is documented as follows (emphasis mine):

> −size n[c]
>
> The  primary  shall evaluate as true if the file size in bytes, divided by
>   512 and **rounded up** to the next integer, is `n`.  If `n` is followed by
>   the character 'c', the size shall be in bytes.

The man page for *GNU* `find` warns that

> The `+` and `-` prefixes signify greater than and less than, as usual, but
>   bear in mind that the size is **rounded up**  to the next unit (so a 1-byte
>   file is not matched by `-size -1M`).

---

#### Use of the `-and` predicate

Finally, the use of the `-and` predicate has nothing to do with how `find` interprets the file sizes. There’s no problem using different units of measurement on either side of `-and` or `-or`.

By the way, `-and` is the default and is used implicitly to combine how multiple predicates are evaluated in a `find` expression; `-and` is actually a GNU extension to `find` so omitting it is better for portability. Also, by leaving it out, you can greatly simplify your `find` expression (also no need for parentheses):

```
find / -type f -size +10M -size -1000M
```

Comment: +1 This seems to be the correct answer, I'm deleting my answer.

Comment: +1 Ok,@Anthony Geoghegan I've trying out with your answer, and the results are ok.  
Thank you very much.